# If the power is not working in a circuit , how do you determine which breaker controls it?

Tags: electrical-panel

If the power is not working in a circuit, how do you determine which breaker controls it?

Comment: Hi - we will need more information than this.  What exactly isn't working?  Some lights are out? None of the outlets have power?  and so on.  Or do you mean that you popped a breaker and want to know how to find it -- in which case look for the breaker where the switch is in a mid-position, unlike all the others.

Comment: Is there power in the rest of the building, just not to the circuit in question, or is the whole building unpowered?

Comment: There are devices that can be plugged into an outlet (I'd imagine they're available with adapters for light sockets) that inject a tone into the wire, which can then be traced with a probe. I don't know how well they work or why the tone wouldn't bleed over into other branch circuits.

Comment: Wow. No one said the obvious answer.  One of the breakers that is in the off position or tripped position might be for that circuit. Sarcasm aside. What circuit is not working? That will help in identifying the power source. General lights and plugs, dedicated outlet, specialized outlet  or something typically that works in tandem with something else?

Comment: @user68386  ummm,, actually, I did mention that in my comment :-)

Comment: Or perhaps the circuit is out but there aren't any popped breakers (i.e., the problem is a bad junction or a tripped GFCI)  The question is very vague.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a circuit that seems dead?

1. Confirm whether the lights work - this shows if its a power cut.
2. Check other sockets in the area using a known-good appliance or plug-in tester - this helps identify if its one bad socket or the whole circuit.
3. Locate the breaker box, open, and look for "work in progress" lockout tags.  Could be someone is working on your circuit and failed to communicate.
4. Sniff.  Really - the nose can be an excellent tool for identifying issues.  Is there a burny smell at any point.  Smell is also a non-contact check.
5. Look for breakers which are in the wrong position.  Do remember that for various reasons a breaker might be installed upside-down, so read the label and don't go by switch left/right position
6. Labels - Depending on the age of your install, it may be well labelled, or not.  Read them and look for a label that matches the room you were in.
7. Fuses - some areas of the world still have fuseable links rather than breakers or cutouts.  These tend to be inside ceramic or Bakelite housings which need to be pulled with some tug to be checked.   Pulling a fuse will stop a circuit, so warn other people, and once you identify a fuse, do label it clearly.

Points not covered, MWBC, US 220V lines, etc.

Lastly, don't ever feel bad about getting a professional to come and do electrical, (pr anything with which you feel uncomfortable)   I personally can't stand plumbing given the possible damage.  **There's no shame in knowing your limits.**